Pandas merge dataframes horizontally on union of common column
I have two dataframes which have a structure similar to the following:
df1

id  name  val
1   a     23
2   b     90
4   c     72


df2

id  name  val
1   d     88
3   e     12
4   f     11

I want them to merge so that the resultant dataframe looks like the one below:
              df1            df2
          name    val    name    val
idx  1    a       23     d       88
     2    b       90     na      na
     3    na      na     e       12
     4    c       72     f       11

How can I achieve this in pandas?

import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,2,3], "name":["a","b","c"], "val":[23,90,72]})
df1.columns = [f"df1_{column}" for column in df1.columns]
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1,3,4], "name":["d","e","f"], "val":[88,12,11]})
df2.columns = [f"df2_{column}" for column in df2.columns]

df3 = pd.concat([df1.set_index("df1_id"), df2.set_index("df2_id")], axis=1)

#   df1_name  df1_val df2_name  df2_val
# 1        a     23.0        d     88.0
# 2        b     90.0      NaN      NaN
# 3        c     72.0        e     12.0
# 4      NaN      NaN        f     11.0


How can I add the information of which column comes from which file? I want to save the dataframe as a csv and that information would be really useful

I've added a simple way. Maybe you want to add multilevel columns instead

I made use of keys to populate the source of the columns
